# Decode HTML Entities in JS to Textbox Value

Tags: javascript, jquery

id like to decode all HTML Entities from a String (named descr, coming from a MySQL-DB)

I use this function to do this:

```
function htmlDecode(input) {
  var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(input, "text/html");
  return doc.documentElement.textContent;
}
```

And this works fine, if i print the value to a div.

```
document.getElementById('ABC').innerHTML = htmlDecode(descr); -> Descr = "&amp;" -> Output in Div "&"
```

But if i print the value to a textarea its not decoded:

```
document.getElementById('ABCD').value = htmlDecode(descr); -> Descr = "&amp;" -> Output in Textarea "&amp;"
```

I spend ours in SO, but didtn find a solution. Can you help me?

Comment: `innerHTML` is placing actual HTML into the element, which is being interpreted by the browser to show cleanly. `value` of a textarea is placing raw text.  What happens when you do NOT decode it for the textarea?

Comment: Sorry, but this is a simple misunderstanding of what HTML is and how the elements work. If you set `&amp;` into a div, it will **render** that to just `&`... if you put it in a textbox (or textarea) it will literally show `&amp;`

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Without decoding the textarea-value, it still shows &amp; Do you know any solution, how i can convert the text to the textarea correctly? Normaly i would use PHP, but i need a JS Solution here

Comment: I assume your MySQL database already has the escaped values. Is that a correct assumption?

Comment: Yes. The DB contains the value &amp;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to a use DOMParser as referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34064434/1024832).

```js
//this function does the unescaping
function htmlDecode(input) {
  var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(input, "text/html");
  return doc.documentElement.textContent;
}

var str="Stars &amp; Stripes";  //arbitrary escaped string

//render the escaped string into the div as-is
document.getElementById("printhere_div").innerHTML = str;

//set the textarea value using the unescaped string
document.getElementById("printhere_textarea").value = htmlDecode(str);
```

```html
<div id="printhere_div">target div</div>
<textarea id="printhere_textarea">target textarea</textarea>
```